# Android MipMaps not working (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, mipmaps, android-icons

So, I set the mipmap folders up in the res/ directory (such as /src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi, and so on, for the different densities), and in the manifest I put the android:icon=@mipmap/ic_launcher for the ic_launcher.png files, yet I still get that android green guy on my phone when i press the play button.  very frustrating.  any suggestions to try?

ive tried uninstalling the app and cleaning the project

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had closed the  tag in the manifest file so it wasn't reading in the mipmap resources

should have been

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        >
```

instead of

```
<application>
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if it is same issue as mine but I removed xml files in folder mipmap-anydpi-v26 after that it do its job

Answer (score 3):

In your Android Studio Inside a package Manager

1. Right click on folder app and select new->Image Asset
2. Default is launcher icon, just select your image and done

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I tried that already to no avail.  It selects the proper image, replaces whatever was in the mipmap folders, but still upon launch gives the green Android default icon.  I might try creating a new project and just pasting my classes into that, maybe some hidden config settings got skewed

Comment: In your androidManifest.xml look inside <application> tag where android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" is define make sure this is a correct path

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it for me in Android Studio

1. Make sure your png image is in the res/drawable folder.
2. Make sure your png image does not contain an uppercase character.

[3. Create App icon using Image Assest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImHzM.png)

[4. Replace "android:icon=ic_launcher" with your icon name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pYkt.png)

5. Rebuild and you are good to go.